# How to calculate distance between two marker points in android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am creating an android app which shows distance and duration of two marker points in the Map. In the onCreate() I have written the following code:

In MapsActivity.java

```
   private List<LatLng> getDirectionPolylines(List<RouteObject> routes){
        List<LatLng> directionList = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        for(RouteObject route : routes){
            List<LegsObject> legs = route.getLegs();
            for(LegsObject leg : legs){
                String routeDistance = leg.getDistance().getText();
                String routeDuration = leg.getDuration().getText();
                setRouteDistanceAndDuration(routeDistance, routeDuration);
                List<StepsObject> steps = leg.getSteps();
                for(StepsObject step : steps){
                    PolylineObject polyline = step.getPolyline();
                    String points = polyline.getPoints();
                    List<LatLng> singlePolyline = decodePoly(points);
                    for (LatLng direction : singlePolyline){
                        directionList.add(direction);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return directionList;
    }
```

I am not clear how to calculate distance & duration in 'getText' in the code above. I was not able to see some APIs like Distancebetween() which is using LtnLtg as references.
Please suggest how to calculate the distance and duration values.

Comment: But you have a list of LatLng objects some lines further down your code...

Comment: Yes how to use it to get these two points?

Answer (score -1):

```
var lat = marker.getPosition().lat();
var lng = marker.getPosition().lng();
```